# Notepad++ rows to columns, in groups

Tags: datatables, notepad++, transpose

I have found a ton of ways to transpose columns to text in Notepad++ and vice versa. However, where I'm struggling is that I have one column with several rows. I can't 'just' transpose these as the data winds up being in the wrong order.

Example:

```
RANK
COMPANY
GROWTH
REVENUE
INDUSTRY
1
Skillz
50,058.92%
$54.2m
Software
2
EnviroSolar Power
36,065.06%
$37.4m
Energy
```

When I transpose this, I wind up with:

```
RANKCOMPANYGROWTHREVENUEINDUSTRY 1Skillz50,058.92%$54.2mSoftware2EnviroSolar Power36,065.06%$37.4mEnergy
```

I need everything to remain in groups so I wind up with the following, noting that I also need a delimiter added:

```
RANK|COMPANY|GROWTH|REVENUE|INDUSTRY
1|Skillz|50,058.92%|$54.2m|Software
2|EnviroSolar Power|36,065.06|$37.4m|Energy
```

As you can see with the company EnviroSolar Power, there is a space between "EnviroSolar" and "Power" and anything I've tried winds up removing the spaces that should remain in tact when transposing.

I appreciate ANY help you can offer! Thank you in advance!

Comment: You'd better write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your rows always start with integers (except for the header row of course) and furthermore, that only the first column contains integers you could do do that with two search replace (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>).

*Be sure to opt for 'Regular expression' search mode.*

**First** replace all newlines with pipes. This will put everything on one line for now.

Find what: `\n`

Replace with: `|`

**Next** find all pure numeric fields and make them start of a line to reach the desired result.

Find what: `\|([0-9]+)\|`

Replace with: `\n$1|`

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of columns, in fact here it is 5, you could do in two steps:

**First:**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:[^\r\n]+\R){5}`
- Replace with: `$0\n`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:             : start non capture group
    [^\r\n]+    : 1 or more any character but line break
    \R          : any kind of line break
){5}            : group must occurs 5 times, 
                  here you can give the columns number of your choice
```

This will add a linebreak after 5 columns.

- *Check regular expression*

**Second:**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(\R)(?!\R)|(\R\R)`
- Replace with: `(?1|:\n)`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(\R)            : any kind of line break, in group 1
(?!\R)          : negative lookahead, make sure we have not another linebreak after
|               : OR
(\R\R)          : 2 line break, in group 2
```

**Replacement:**

```
(?1             : conditional replacement, is group 1 existing
  |             : yes ==> a pipe
 :\n            : no ==> linebreak
)               : end condition
```

This will replace a single linebreak by a pipe and 2 consecutive linebreaks by a single one

**Result for given example:**

```
RANK|COMPANY|GROWTH|REVENUE|INDUSTRY
1|Skillz|50,058.92%|$54.2m|Software
2|EnviroSolar Power|36,065.06%|$37.4m|Energy
```

Comment: For this to take the format of the required result you will also need to go and remove the pipes from the start of the line by regex searching for `^\|` and replacing with nothing.