# Converting a column to row CSV in Notepad++

Tags: csv, notepad++

I have 1 column of characters, they are stock ticker symbols, and each is on its own line. I need to convert this to 1 row with each ticker separated by a comma.

From something like:

mmm

axp

.

.

.

To something like:

mmm,axp,...

Is there a way to do this easily inside of Notepad++ ?

Thanks!!

Comment: Find: `\R` ; Replace: `,`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Notepad++ rows to columns, in groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45969411/notepad-rows-to-columns-in-groups)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 1):

If you use Windows Carriage Return

[image]

You can run simply this search & replace

[image]

to have

[image]